# Find joint distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I have tried multiple ways, but I do not know where to start on the following problem:

> Let $X, Y, Z$ be r.v.’s defined on common probability space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), m)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ is the Borel set on $[0,1]$. Find joint distribution $X, Y, Z$ which maximizes $\min \{P(X>Y), P(Y>Z), P(Z>X)\}$.

Comment: What is $m$? Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, it is Lebesgue measure. I am sorry, I should have specified this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
1 &\geq\mathbb{P}(X>Y \: or \: Y>Z \: or \: Z>X) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(X>Y)+\mathbb{P}(Y>Z)+\mathbb{P}(Z>X) -(\mathbb{P}(X>Y>Z)+\mathbb{P}(Y>Z>X)+\mathbb{P}(Z>X>Y))
\end{align*}
Where
$$\mathbb{P}(X>Y>Z)+\mathbb{P}(Y>Z>X)+\mathbb{P}(Z>X>Y) \leq 1,$$
since these events are disjoint. Combining this with our first inequality we get, that
$$\mathbb{P}(X>Y)+\mathbb{P}(Y>Z)+\mathbb{P}(Z>X) \leq 2$$
so $$\min(\mathbb{P}(X>Y),\mathbb{P}(Y>Z), \mathbb{P}(Z>X))\leq \frac{2}{3}.$$
Now consider the random vector
$$(X,Y,Z)(\omega) := \begin{cases}(3,2,1) &\omega \in [0,1/3] \\
(1,3,2) &\omega \in (1/3,2/3] \\ (2,1,3) &\omega \in (2/3,1]  \end{cases}$$
and verify, that this vector satisfies $\min(\mathbb{P}(X>Y),\mathbb{P}(Y>Z), \mathbb{P}(Z>X)) = \frac{2}{3}$ and must therefore be a solution to the given problem.